# Why are games locked at a certain frame per second?

Tags: performance

A lot of PC games are locked at 60 frames per second. I know that this is because a high frame rate can cause glitches/bug in a game and mess up the physics but is there another reason? Should anyone who makes games lock their games at 30-120fps? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasons the games are commonly "locked" at 60fps is that displays can't render faster than that.  Further more, to make sure the rendered frames get to the screen with minimal delay and to prevent tearing (only a portion of the screen getting updated which looks flickery and bad), a frame will be rendered and will wait for the monitor to finish it's redraw cycle before going to the display.  This is called "vsync" and normally happens 60 times a second unsurprisingly!  You can actually turn it off if you want to, but it usually just makes the game look worse.  Check out this Wikipedia page for more info:  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing#V-sync

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't need more frames per second.

Most computer monitors I know have their refresh rate around 60 Hz. Going beyond that, you would not notice the difference.

More FPS for physics means a smoother simulation, but there is a point beyond which you don't gain much.

Also, having more frames to pack in each second means you have less time for your game logic each frame. Locking the frame rate means the programmers know how much time they have for each task during a frame.

Comment: Both of the answers are right but I put the top one as correct because it has some more detail. I wish I could say both are correct -_-

Comment: @Chickenator no offense taken :)

Comment: You can run physics simulation decoupled from rendering thus at a higher frame rate then 60 FPS.